# Boolean's value is acting as true but is listed as false?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, boolean

I'm creating a simple tic-tac-toe game and I have a boolean called winAlert that if it is true it should alert the player that they have won. This works correctly for the most part, but there is one instance where it does not. If the game is won and all of the cells are filled, the console logs that winAlert's value is false, but it still alerts the player that they have won, as if it were true. Could someone look over this code and see why this is behaving in this way? http://jsfiddle.net/Z5c9P/3/
This function is where I think the problem lies, but I don't know for sure.

```
var determineWin = function (pMoves) {
    for (var i = 0; i < winConditions.length; i++) {
        if (winConditions[i].length > pMoves.length) {
            continue;
        }
        for (var j = 0; j < winConditions[i].length; j++) {
            winAlert = false;
            for (var k = 0; k < pMoves.length; k++) {
                if (pMoves[k] === winConditions[i][j]) {
                    winAlert = true;
                    break;
                }

            }
            if (!winAlert) break;
        }
        if (winAlert) {
            alert(currentPlayer + " wins!");
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

Here's the code that calls this function:

```
$('td').one('click', function () {
    turnCount += 1;
    setCurrentPlayer();
    $(this).text(currentPlayer);
    cellTracker = $(this).attr('id');
    storeMoves();
    determineWin(xMoves);
    determineWin(oMoves);
    if(turnCount === 9 && winAlert === false) {
        alert("Tie game!");
    }
    console.log(turnCount, xMoves, oMoves, winAlert);
});
```

Comment: Where is the console log happening that you feel disagrees with winalert?

Comment: Do you declare `winAlert` anywhere? If no, what happens if you declare `var winAlert = false` before function call?

Comment: I have it log winAlert's value in my second event handler near the bottom of the code.
If you win the game by having X click on cells 3, 4, 6, 8, and 9; and O clicking on the rest while viewing the console you will see what I mean.

Comment: Do not use `break` instruction to compensate a lack of `while` instruction. This will simplify a lot.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter I declare winAlert at the very beginning of the code along with most of my other variables.

Comment: @Frederik.L what do you suggest I do instead?

Comment: @user2449973 `for` will be useful when you can quantify how many iterations there will be before entering the loop, and `while` will be when you cannot. For checking the winning criteria, it would be easier to debug if it fits in a `while` in order to avoid jumpy behavior.

Comment: @Frederik.L I don't understand what you mean, sorry.

Comment: @Frederik.L I would love to see an example so I could try and understand what you mean. I honestly don't understand the determineWin function very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because your code does the following:

```
storeMoves();
determineWin(xMoves);
determineWin(oMoves);
if(turnCount === 9 && winAlert === false) {
    alert("Tie game!");
}
console.log(turnCount, xMoves, oMoves, winAlert);
```

So if X ever wins the game, `determineWin(xMoves)` will set the variable to true, and `determinWin(oMoves)` will set it back to false, all before the `console.log()`

One way to solve this would be to only check for a win for the current player's moves:

```
storeMoves();
determineWin(currentPlayer == 'X' ? xMoves : yMoves);
if(turnCount === 9 && winAlert === false) {
    alert("Tie game!");
}
console.log(turnCount, xMoves, oMoves, winAlert);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the most effective/ simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have called `determineWin` on each player. so if x wins, `determineWin(oMoves);` will make `winAlert` false. Is this the problem?
Maybe you should create a new `determineWin` which only called once to determine who is the winner.

this code will just skip another user(so `winAlert` is still true) when his cell is less than 3, so this problem doesn't need fill all cells but just each player has more than 3 cells.

```
    if (winConditions[i].length > pMoves.length) {
        continue;
    }
```

Comment: The second time you call `determineWin()`, winAlert gets set back to false.

Comment: I would agree but if you try winning in any other way, it disproves this. winAlert(at least for that turnCount) is equal to true.

Comment: No need to fill all cells. when each player fills more than 3 cell, it happens. here is the log `7 ["c1", "c2", "c6", "c3"] ["c4", "c5", "c8"] false` which x wins and the `winAlert` is false

Comment: @jcsanyi wouldn't calling determineWin() on oMoves before xMoves solve this issue then, seeing as O cannot win on the 9th move if it goes second?

Comment: @leonhart I just discovered that swapping the order in which I call determineWin() solves this too, although I don't know why.

Comment: No, swapping doesn't actually solve the problem - just that particular case. It would introduce the same problem whenever O wins instead.

Comment: @jcsanyi but O can't win on the 9th turn seeing as O goes second.
And the only time a tie needs to be declared is if all 9 cells have been filled an nobody has won.
So doesn't that solve it?

Comment: Yes, that might solve the immediate problem of declaring a tie after a win - but it doesn't actually solve the root problem of the winAlert variable not being what you expect. It makes your code harder to understand and maintain later. See my answer for what I think is a better solution.

Comment: @user2449973 no, that won't solve the whole problme, see this log:`8 ["c1", "c4", "c9", "c3"] ["c2", "c5", "c6", "c8"] false`. I have swapped the order but `winAlert` is still false

Answer (score 0):

i change a little your code [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z5c9P/23/)

```
 var determineWin = function (pMoves) {
    for (var i = 0; i < winConditions.length; i++) {
        if (winConditions[i].length > pMoves.length) {
            continue;
        }

        winAlert = false;
        matches = 0;
        for (var j = 0; j < winConditions[i].length; j++) {                       
            for (var k = 0; k < pMoves.length; k++) {
                if (pMoves[k] === winConditions[i][j]) {                        
                    matches++;
                }            
            }               
        }
        if (matches == 3) return true;



    }
   return false;
};
```

and then

```
  $('td').one('click', function () {
    turnCount += 1;
    setCurrentPlayer();
    $(this).text(currentPlayer);
    cellTracker = $(this).attr('id');
    storeMoves();
    if (determineWin(xMoves)){ // this is changed
        alert("X Win")
        return;
    };
    if (determineWin(oMoves)){
        alert("O Win")
        return;
    };
    if(turnCount === 9 && winAlert === false) {
        alert("Tie game!");
    }
    console.log(turnCount, xMoves, oMoves, winAlert);
});
```

** Updated to clarify

Comment: This function  now return true if the pMoves make match with a the winCondition[x] in the 3 positions. So when you call it you can use this if (determineWin(xMoves)){ alert...} else if (.... check the fiddle